# when I Try to set Default value in Reactive Forms it Shows me NULL

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I crate 1 Reactive form and try to set default which is comes from function when i try to do that the value shows me null

[image: Stop Timer Code]

here is some code picture. you can get some idea not necessary to read

[image: Reactive Form Code]

Here is code of Reactive Form where i'm storing the Default value

[image: Output]

here you can see the output of code that it shows the null value

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set value Directly like you declare

Use `patchValue`

Code:

```
this.projectForm.patchValue({
      p_startTime: this.starttime,
      p_endTime: this.endtime,
      P_sessionTime:this.totaltime
    });
```

use this code in pauseTimer()